# Tail recursion in Bash

Tags: bash, recursion, tail-recursion

I've tried to write a script to verify that all the stats of a metrics are positive before I make any further changes using the service. The part I'm stuck at is thinking over how to tail the recursion for the following use-case :

```
function load_cache() {
    cacheStat=( $(curl -s -X GET "http://localhost:${MET_PORT}/metrics" | sed 's/\\\\\//\//g' | sed 's/[{}]//g' | awk -v k="cacheSize" '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}' | sed 's/\"\:\"/\|/g' | sed 's/[\,]/ /g' | sed 's/\"//g' | grep -w "cacheSize" | cut -d ':' -f 2) )

    # the above gives me the ouput(cacheStat) as -
    # 2.0
    # 311.0
    # 102.0

    count=0
    for index in ${!cacheStat[*]}
    do
        if [[ ${cacheStat[$index]} -le 0 ] && [ $count -lt 3 ]]; then
            sleep .5
            count=$[$count +1];
            load_cache
            #Wouldn't the above initialise `count` to 0 again.
        fi
    done
}
```

What I am trying to do is if any of the elements in the cacheStat is less than or equal to `0`, then sleep for `.5` secs and query the cacheStat again and perform the check on all its elements again. Though not do this more than 3 times for which I am trying to use `count.

Open to any suggestion to improve the script.

---

***Update*** - 
On modifying the scripts as suggested by @Inian to

```
RETRY_COUNT=0
function load_cache() {
    cacheStat=( $(curl -s -X GET "http://localhost:${MET_PORT}/metrics" | sed 's/\\\\\//\//g' | sed 's/[{}]//g' | awk -v k="cacheSize" '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}' | sed 's/\"\:\"/\|/g' | sed 's/[\,]/ /g' | sed 's/\"//g' | grep -w "cacheSize" | cut -d ':' -f 2) );
    for index in ${!cacheStat[*]}
    do
        echo "Stat - ${cacheStat[$index]}"
        if (( ${cacheStat[$index]} <= 0 )) && (( $RETRY_COUNT < 3 )); then
            echo "Attempt count - ${RETRY_COUNT}"
            sleep .5s
            RETRY_COUNT=$((RETRY_COUNT +1));
            load_cache
        fi
    done
}
```

The logs read -

```
>     > + cacheStat=($(curl -s -X GET "http://localhost:${MET_PORT}/metrics" | sed 's/\\\\\//\//g' | sed
> 's/[{}]//g' | awk -v k="cacheSize"
>     > '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}' | sed
>     > 's/\"\:\"/\|/g' | sed 's/[\,]/ /g' | sed 's/\"//g' | grep -w
>     > "cacheSize" | cut -d ':' -f 2))
>     > ++ curl -s -X GET http://localhost:8181/metrics
>     > ++ sed 's/\\\\\//\//g'
>     > ++ sed 's/[{}]//g'
>     > ++ sed 's/[\,]/ /g'
>     > ++ awk -v k=cacheSize '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}'
>     > ++ sed 's/\"\:\"/\|/g'
>     > ++ cut -d : -f 2
>     > ++ sed 's/\"//g'
>     > ++ grep -w cacheSize
```

It doesn't even iterate I guess.

Comment: Your script has couple of syntax issues. Fix it  before trying it back, are you sure this worked?

Comment: @Inian It didn't. That's why sharing it. And could you please point out the flaws. Consider me a newbie to bash. Trying to execute the script all I get to see is until `count=0` and nothing ahead of it. Even if I put an `echo` there.

Comment: Refer my answer below, foremost remove infinite recursion by moving `count` outside the function.

Comment: @nullpointer The `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, `cut` you have piped after the `curl` command can likely be simplify by only using `sed` or `awk`. Please provide the output of the `curl` command if you want some help here.

Comment: @oliv already shared with the script(next statement) if you look close :)

Comment: @Inian Nope. It doesn't. Updated the question.

Comment: @nullpointer: Are you sure the array `cacheStat` is not empty? Can you print its value before the for-loop? Why is the `echo` statements not seen?

Comment: @Inian trying to execute the curl individually, it certainly gives me the output as
 `# 2.0
    # 311.0
    # 102.0`. Hoping the way I'm trying to save it to a list in `cacheStat` is not incorrect.

Comment: @nullpointer: Can you print the array and paste the output as I requested before?

Comment: @Inian works fine now. The reason being the list empty was guessed correctly. PS - The list was empty since the curl above requires a service to respond.. and this needed some delay in the previous method call(start) and this method call. (load_cache). Thanks.

Comment: The repeated `sed` and `awk` calls are a massive antipattern.  See [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) which generalizes nicely to anything with more than two of any of `sed`, `awk`, and `grep`.

Comment: Looks like you are obscurely hard-coding a poor man's JSON decoder anyway.  Try moving to a language which supports JSON, such as `jq`.

Comment: For all that noise, probably all you need is `curl | sed -n 's/.*[, ]"cacheSize": *\(-[1-9]\|0\).*/\1/p'` to find if there is at least one value which is zero or negative.

Comment: @tripleee yes using the JSON decoder to form a list of values of a specific attribute. The one shared above by you doesn't get me that though. Don't have the link handy, would share if I find the use case over the net.

Comment: If you mean the `sed` snippet, it's a bit speculative.  If you need to support floating point, the regex needs to be slightly more complex.  Anyway, for legibility I'd still go with `jq`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the infinite recursion by moving the `count=0` outside the function body.

Also your script has couple of issues, a syntax violation and an outdated construct, lines `12-14` should have been,

```
if [[ ${cacheStat[$index]} -le 0 ]] && [[ $count -lt 3 ]]; then
    sleep .5s
    count=$((count +1));
    load_cache
fi
```

or) use a more readable arithmetic operator, `(())` in the `if-clause` as

```
if (( ${cacheStat[$index]} <= 0 )) && (( $count < 3 )); then
```

> `bash` does not inherently support floating point arithmetic (comparison in your case), use a third party tool like `bc`, `awk` for this,

```
if (( $(echo "${cacheStat[$index]} <= 0" | bc -l) )) && (( $count < 3 )); then
```

Comment: Also, the comparison currently gives an output as  `syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0 <= 0.0 ")`. Since our input becomes `2.0`

Comment: you cannot compare float values in `bash`. Not working for you, does not mean the answer is not right, by un-accepting it.

Comment: hmmm, I see. I think I would convert it to int then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid all that ad-hoc JSON parsing by using a JSON parser.

```
# Avoid using Bash-only "function" keyword
load_cache () {
    local try
    for try in 1 2 3; do
        # Suction: jq doesn't return non-zero exit code for no match
        # work around that by piping to grep .
        if curl -s -X GET "http://localhost:${MET_PORT}/metrics" |
            jq '.[] | select(cacheSize < 0)' |
            grep .
        then
            # Notice also redirection to stderr for diagnostic messages
            echo "$0: Attempt $try failed, sleeping before retrying" >&2
            sleep 0.5
        else
            # Return with success, we are done, exit function
            return 0
        fi
    done

    # Return failure
    return 1
}
```

I see no reason to prefer recursion over a straightforward `for` loop for controlling the number of retries.

If you never want to see the offending values, you can use `grep -q` in the conditional.  I'm expecting you would do `load_cache >/dev/null` if you don't want the output.

If you want to see the non-offending values, the code will need some refactoring, but I'm focusing on getting the central job done elegantly and succinctly.  Here's a sketch, mainly to show you the `jq` syntax for that.

```
load_cache () {
    local try
    local results
    for try in 1 2 3; do
        results=$(curl -s -X GET "http://localhost:${MET_PORT}/metrics" |
            jq '.[] | .cacheSize' | tr '\n' ' ')
        echo "$0: try $try: cacheSize $results" >&2
        # Funky: massage the expression we test againt into a normalized form
        # so that we know that the value will always be preceded by a space
        case " $results " in
          *" 0 "* | *" -"* )
             case $try in
              3) echo "$0: try $try failed; aborting" >&2 ;;
              *) echo "$0: try $try failed; sleeping before retrying" >&2
                 sleep 0.5 ;;
             esac;;
          *) return 0
        esac
    done
    return 1
}
```

The nested `case` to avoid sleeping on the final iteration isn't particularly elegant, but at least it should ensure that the reader is awake. /-8